# How do i display the subcategory of Post type in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

My Category Structure is like below
Category structure:

```
Product 1
Product 2
    Product 2.1
    Product 2.2
Product 3
Product 4
    Product 4.1
    Product 4.2
```

How can i get all the category & its sub category in WordPress.
My Post type name is Product & Taxonomy name is productcategory

Comment: have a look at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/list-all-subcategories-from-category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might help you..

```
<?php
//list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories  (also useful as a widget)
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$taxonomy = 'genre';
$title = '';

$args = array(
  'orderby' => $orderby,
  'show_count' => $show_count,
  'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
  'depth'    => 2,
  'hide_empty' => 0,
  'title_li' => $title
);
?>
<ul>
<?php
wp_list_categories($args);
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this useful code. I have already done this in my project. i can see the list of categories but i cant not see the sub categories

Comment: Hi.. there !! 'depth' => 1 is not working. It is giving the same output

Comment: Add to the array `'hide_empty' => 0` and the `depth` should be 0 or 2 to show all children from all levels too... 2 will show you the top level and the children for the top level.